# Ubuntu deprecating AMD fglrx driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon, fglrx

I just read that the latest stable release 16.04 will no longer use the AMD fglrx driver, and thus purge it at upgrading to 16.04 LTS. My question is, since I'm using hybrid graphics with AMD Radeon R9 HD8700 and onboard Intel Graphics, switching between the Catalyst driver and Intel - should I just do a clean install of the latest version or choose to upgrade? I am not worried about the data, the computer is relatively new, but will it be safe to upgrade?

Is there any place I can check the supported graphic cards for the 16.04 version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking "close source or open source drivers" AMDGPU is the new fglrx for newer cards and display servers.  With a hybrid card, my guess is the best support would be out of this driver, but that idea lacks testing.

Also, for anyone that doesn't know, deprecated means:
*We plan to remove completely in the future, but it still works for now*.
Just for clarity.

With corner cases, I always do a clean install.  Getting switchable graphics working exactly how you want, at current, I still consider a relatively risky corner case.  So, I would do a clean install if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are many answers about this already.
You will have support for HD cards (probably) but by using the opensource driver (radeon) which works pretty fine.

the fglrx driver nor catalyst work anymore, is not just deprecated it won't even install.

there's a new closed source driver "amdgpu-pro" http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver–Release-Notes.aspx
but its in beta and doesnt support old cards. My card is a r7 260x it says it's supported but still doesnt work because it says it's not being detected.