# State of AMD drivers in 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx, amd-graphics

I am really confused about the state of AMD drivers on 16.04

My question is six-fold.

---

1. What is the difference between

   - The `amdgpu` driver,
   - The `radeon` driver, and
   - The `amdgpu-pro` driver?

---

2. When would each of those drivers be used?
3. Are they all open-source?
4. Can you switch between them?
5. Which GPUs are supported?
6. Is AMD working on an `fglrx` replacement for 16.04?

---

As I do not have an AMD card, I am unable to experiment.

I understand this is a broad question, but I want this to be a canonical question :)

Comment: A community wiki answer might be good so that we don't end up with a ton of answers.

Comment: 3. yes open source. 6. no they abandoned fglrx and are focusing on open source. version 15.x.x was the last closed source amd driver featuring the fglrx. -- also, i agree a good wiki that answers it all would be very helpful about this. the information on much of this is scattered everywhere in no particular place.

Comment: "I understand this is a broad question, but I want this to be a canonical question :)" Then you need to update the answer, it does not even answer all your questions or include anything about usage or installation of the drivers or what chips they support. If you want to make it a Canonical question, it must include all relevant information. i am voting to close this as too broad, I don't know why it is still open. i suggest you update it a lot before it is reviewed.

Comment: @MarkKirby - I know it needs work. And I **will** get to it eventually...

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've been able to find so far:

1. - A: The `amdgpu` driver, pre-installed in 16.04, is used for AMD's newest graphics cards. <sup>[3](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU)</sup>
   - B: The `radeon` driver, also pre-installed in 16.04<sup>[1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)</sup>, is a replacement for the `fglrx` driver<sup>[1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)</sup>, and is used for older AMD cards that `amdgpu` doesn't support.
   - C: `amdgpu-pro` is not its own driver, but rather an overlay on top of `amdgpu`<sup>[2](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3075837/linux/amds-gaming-optimized-amdgpu-pro-driver-for-linux-is-in-beta.html)</sup>. It is optimized for gaming<sup>[2](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3075837/linux/amds-gaming-optimized-amdgpu-pro-driver-for-linux-is-in-beta.html)</sup>.
2. I think Ubuntu decides automatically. Although the `amdgpu-pro` driver has to be downloaded manually.
3. - The `amdgpu` driver is completely open-source
   - The `radeon` driver is completely open-source
   - The `amdgpu-pro` driver is partially open-source
4. I have no idea. Probably not.
5. Still have to do more research....
6. `amdgpu-pro` is the replacement for `fglrx`.

Comment: `amdgpu-pro` is not installed in Ubuntu. It is a new proprietary driver that can be downloaded from AMD site.

Comment: @Pilot6 - I didn't say it was.

Comment: You said that Ubuntu "decides automatically". And in general it looks like the driver is installed.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Edited.