# AMDGPU or Radeon for my GPU

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics

I have a `3DClub Radeon 7790 1GB` and plan to use 16.04. What driver do i need for my GPU? In some places i found that my card is supported in the `amdgpu` driver. Is that true? If so - how to install it?

Comment: Here's a FAQ on this subject that I've been working on. Might contain some useful information to you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/796067/state-of-amd-drivers-in-16-04

Comment: Thanks for the info. I knew some stuff already. I cant still find out is the 7790 supported. I saw several threads that say it is and some incl. the `amdgpu-pro` page that says its not.
Edit: in general i care only for the `amdgpu`. Pro version or not. I know that radeon driver is far from ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your card should support AMDGPU, [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756258/which-graphics-cards-are-supported-by-the-new-amdgpu-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04)

The installation steps [from AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx) are

```
mkdir /tmp
cd tmp
wget https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-315407.tar.xz
​tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-315407.tar.xz
cd amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-315407
amdgpu-pro-driver/amdgpu-pro-install
```

Ensure that your user account is a member of the "video" group prior to using the vulkan driver. You can find which groups you are a member of with the following command:

```
groups
```

If not add yourself

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME
```

That should be it, to check it installed

```
dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
```

To remove it

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will try this after work and will let you know how it went.
EDIT: I saw that thread before i posted mine. This list is for Radeon Driver, not `amdgpu`...