# AMDGPU-PRO driver not working and ubntu is fraazing randomly [ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

Dears,

i am new to linux, i am using Ubntu 16.04  and my video card type AMD Radeon and my PC is

```
mohammed@Jakri:~$ lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A1
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Lenovo Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [17aa:3815]
```

also see the below output:

```
mohammed@Jakri:~$ lspci -nn |egrep "VGA|Display" 
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation  Haswell-ULT   Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
0a:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230] [1002:666f] (rev ff)
```

my problem is that the GUI is freezing randomly and sometimes slow of response, i knew (from googling) that The fglrx driver is now deprecated in 16.04, so i tried to install AMDGPU-PRO driver using the below link

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

but the after restarting the machine my screen, start flashing and luncher tool-bar is not working until i UN-installed the AMD driver. i suspect in the partitions that i created during my installation of Linux blow snap of the fdisk command output shown the partitions and their details

```
Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048   31250431  31248384  14.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda2    31250432   89843711  58593280    28G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3    89843712   90234879    391168   191M EFI System
/dev/sda4    90234880 1066797055 976562176 465.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  1066797056 1953523711 886726656 422.8G Linux filesystem
```

hope that you can assist me on this, i am very exited to move from windows 10 to Linux  but this issue is disturb me alot.

Comment: First run `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro` to make sure the driver is installed correctly. If so, make sure your user (no root) is in the video group `groups` and if not add yourself `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME`. Also, your `lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A1` says you are connected to integrated intel graphics, not an amd card, are you plugged in to the wrong device?

Comment: Also, if you are new to Ubuntu, you don't need all those partitions, they just make it hard for you. one as `/` and one as `swap` is all you need. IDK how that would effect video though, drivers go to `/`.

Comment: IDK what happened to your comment but it says it is not installed, here are some instructions I re wrote for clarity http://askubuntu.com/questions/810025/amdgpu-or-radeon-for-my-gpu/810030?noredirect=1#comment1224570_810030

Comment: the output for `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro` command shows that no package found, and my laptop contains these two graphic cards, how can i unable the AMD one. i laready update the thread incluing the output for `lspci -nn |egrep "VGA|Display"`

Comment: According to the release notes http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx andgpu-pro is not compatible with R5 chipsets, looks like it has no support for laptop GPUs.

Comment: is there any other driver i could install, that supports my AMD card?

Comment: Just the open source one that is preinstalled, amd support is amess on Ubuntu right now but that OS driver is not bad, it can do 3d acceleration.

Comment: I thought it only hangs with the driver installed? Incompatible driver would explain that.